# A question about the phrase

Tags: wallets, passphrase

Found on my computer seed phrase with 6 words in it. Please tell me which wallet accepts this number of words

Answer (score 0):

try it from the command line.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ganache-cli

ganache-cli -m "word1 word2 word3 word4 word5 word6"